# .NET Core filter with contains not working

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

Ok so I have searched for this and have found all kinds of things that seem to be the right answer but I cannot seem to get this working. I think I am close.

I have gotten this code to work in my controller which I call from Datatable serverside ajax:

```
 var shares = await _dataService.GetAllAgencyShares();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDirection))
            {
                shares = shares.AsQueryable().OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDirection);
                
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
            {
                
                shares = shares.Where(m => m.FirstName == searchValue
                         || m.LastName == searchValue
                         || m.AgencyName == searchValue
                         || m.FormId.ToString() == searchValue);
                
            }
 recordsTotal = shares.Count();
            var data = shares.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            var jsonData = new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data };
            return Ok(jsonData);
```

The problem is I would like the search part

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
{
 shares = shares.Where(m => m.FirstName == searchValue
                         || m.LastName == searchValue
                         || m.AgencyName == searchValue
                         || m.FormId.ToString() == searchValue);
}
 recordsTotal = shares.Count();
 var data = shares.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
 var jsonData = new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = 
 recordsTotal, data = data };
 return Ok(jsonData);
```

to find anything "like" searchValue.  Currently this finds exact matches.

I have tried using Contains but I believe that to be boolean. Most things I found are using EF and use IQueryable--I am not using EF.  I have tried to cast IEnumerable as Queryable and nothing seems to work.

Comment: `shares = await _dataService.GetAllAgencyShares() .... shares = shares.AsQueryable()`? is shares `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`? Are you trying to do a DB query, or filter in memory?

Comment: It starts out as IEnumerable, then I cast/convert to AsQueryable to get the OrderBy working (which worked, but wasn't even sure that was correct).   I want to do a filter in memory I believe, and present the filtered list to the user.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you use `.Contains()`?

It works fine if implemented like this;

```
shares = shares.Where(m => m.FirstName.Contains(searchValue)
                         || m.LastName.Contains(searchValue)
                         || m.AgencyName.Contains(searchValue)
                         || m.FormId.ToString().Contains(searchValue));
```

Comment: When I use that, ````recordsTotal = shares.Count();```` would error out, object reference not set

Comment: When using contains and I break on ````recordsTotal = shares.Count();````  it shows "shares" is null--Almost like shares is not getting the filtered list.